# Question about localization by maximal ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have some questions about localization by maximal ideals.

Let $A$ be commutative ring and $p ⊂ A$ be a prime ideal.

then $A_p$ is local ring with maximal ideal $m = pA_p$.

Then I have question that

(i)  $m^2 = p^2A_p$ is it correct?

Nextly $R$ be commutative ring and $m$ be its maximal ideal.

Here I have question.

(ii) $m/m^2$ and $mR_m/m^2R_m$ are isomorphic.

(iii) $m/m^2$ and $mR_m/(mR_m)^2$ are isomorphic.

Are these correct?

Regarding (ii) and (iii), if possible, please state proofs.

This may be a silly question, but I would be grateful if you  answer.(Also, I'm sorry for my poor English.)

Comment: Yes, all claims are correct.